# Common Watch for Multiple Controllers in Angular

Tags: angularjs

mainApp has two controllers with different functionalities. Some of their functions are common.

```
mainApp.controller("WriteController", function($scope) {

    $scope.$watch('task.file.prefix', function (term) {
        term = term.replace(/\\/g,'/');
        $scope.task.file.prefix = term;
    });
});

mainApp.controller("ReadController", function($scope) {

    $scope.$watch('task.file.prefix', function (term) {
        term = term.replace(/\\/g,'/');
        $scope.task.file.prefix = term;
    });
});
```

You can clearly see that I am using two watch (same) for both of controllers. Is there a way that we move out these $watch out of controller to somewhere outside (service or so) to satisfy DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if someone got better workaround but you can try this

```js
mainApp.service('watcher', function(){
    return {
        term : function (newValue) {
            // we don't need scope here because newValue is the scope being watched. 
            // newValue changed = equivalent of $scope. being watch changed.
            newValue = newValue.replace(/\\/g,'/');
        }
    }
})

mainApp.controller("WriteController", function($scope, watcher) {
    // passing the function (do not execute it)
    $scope.$watch('task.file.prefix', watcher.term);
});

mainApp.controller("ReadController", function($scope, watcher) {
    // passing the function (do not execute it)
    $scope.$watch('task.file.prefix', watcher.term);
});
```

Comment: Still looking for better solution. I have not got better than this yet.